# Unnecessary step in Dugundji's construction of an embedding of a completely regular space into a product of closed intervals?

Tags: general-topology

On p. 155 of James Dugundji's *Topology*, we read [here $\mathscr{C}$ denotes set complement]:

[image]

My question is: do we really need $V$? Wouldn't it suffice to invoke complete regularity to get a function $f: Y\rightarrow E^1$ such that $f(p)=1$ and $f(\mathscr{C} U)=0$? Because we'd still end up with $p\in f^{-1}(]0,1])=:V_f \subset U$, which is what we wanted. Am I missing something?

Comment: No. Yes. No. (in order of questions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you don't need $V$, if $f[U^\complement]=\{0\}$ we already have $p \in V_f \subseteq U$ (as $x \notin U$ implies $f(x)=0$ so $x \notin V_f$, the contrapositive).

So the $V_f$ form a base and we still have $$\rho[V_f] = \pi_{f_0}^{-1}[(0,1]] \cap \rho[Y]$$ so that the images of basic open sets are open in $\rho[Y]$.

So you're right. But superfluous is not wrong, only potentially confusing perhaps.